# How to make source code of dependent projects available for gwt compiler?

Tags: java, maven, gwt

Currently I'm trying to set up a GWT project, not a completely new one, I've only replaced some of the dependencies resp. I've introduced new ones.

I've got a multi-project project which is generating a lot of java files (dto's) by using xtext. As result of one these projects a .jar and a sources.jar get created.

These jars I've added added as maven dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx-gwt</artifactId>
    <version>${xxx.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx-gwt</artifactId>
    <version>${xxx.version}</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Eclipse didn't show any errors. In the package explorer the maven dependencies are available.

If I try to compile my gwt project with the new dependencies I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/xxx/.../.../.../xxxDetailPresenterImpl.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 82: No source code is available for type com.xxx.xxx.dto.xxxDetailResultSetDto; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Any idea? All dependent projects which are used in the client part must be available as sources. This project is available as sources...

I've read about the possibility to define a module in the referenced projects and afterwards inherit it in the gwt.xml. But to be honest, I don't know how, because the dependent project is completely automatically generated. Eclipse said, it is not even a Java project.

Comment: I've resolved the problem by creating a gwt.xml in the depended project and inheriting it in my current one. No it works fine. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. All dependent projects which are used in the client part must be available as sourcesfor GWT to compile. For you case,

1. You need to create a skeleton maven module in eclipse,
2. To this module structure need to generate all source xtext.
3. Create gwt.xml in this module skeleton
4. Include following in you POM, to specify the the location of this gwt.xml to gwt maven compiler

   ```
      <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/java</directory>
           <includes>
               <include>**/*.java</include>
               <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
           </includes>
       </resource>
    </resources>
   ```
5. Add this module as dependency to your current module
6. Install dependent module first. Then
7. Install your current module.

Hope this will work. Thanks

Comment: Where must be the skeleton maven module and the gwt.xml created ? I understand what you want to do, but I do not fully understand how to apply it.

Comment: Create a new  gwt maven  project  in eclipse workspace.

1. Right Click New Maven Project ->Give Project Name -> Next -> Select org.cohouse.mojo maven plugin ....

add you project. It will automatically create project structure for you

Answer (score 1):

If you use GWT-Mavent plugin :

http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/project.html#Multi-project_setup

In a nutshell here is what you need to do

In your main project, inside the configuration part of the gwt-maven plugin

```
<configuration>
...
<compileSourcesArtifacts>
    <artifact>com.xxx.xxx:xxx-gwt</artifact>
</compileSourcesArtifacts>
</configuration>
```

Inside the YOURAPP.gwt.xml do not forget to add the classes that needs to be compiled

```
<inherits name='com.xxx.xxx' />
...

<source path='com/xxx/xxx/client' />
```

Inside the project from which you want to use the sources

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>source-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```